# ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack (Python 2)

Tags: python, valueerror, chdir

I am trying to replicate another researcher's findings by using the Python file that he added as a supplement to his paper. It is the first time I am diving into Python, so the error might be extremely simple to fix, yet after two days I haven't still. For context, in the Readme file there's the following instruction:

"To run the script, make sure Python2 is installed. Put all files into one folder designated as “cf_dir”.
 In the script I get an error at the following lines:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
cf_dir, cf_file, cf_phys_file = sys.argv[1:4]
os.chdir(cf_dir)
cf = pd.read_csv(cf_file)
cf_phys = pd.read_csv(cf_phys_file)
```

**ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack**

The "cf_file" and "cf_phys_file" are two major components of all files that are in the one folder named "cf_dir". The "cf_phys_file" relates only to two survey question's (Q22 and Q23), and the "cf_file" includes all other questions 1-21. Now it seems that the code is meant to retrieve those two files from the directory? Only for the "cf_phys_file" the columns 1:4 are needed. The current working directory is already set at the right location.

The path where I located "cf_dir" is as follows:
C:\Users\Marc-Marijn Ossel\Documents\RSM\Thesis\Data\Suitable for ML\Data en Artikelen\Per task Suitability for Machine Learning score readme\cf_dir

**Alternative option in readme file**,

In the readme file there's this option, but also here I cannot understand how to direct the path to the right location:

"Run the following command in an open terminal (substituting for file names
below): python cfProcessor_AEAPnP.py cf_dir cf_file cf_phys_file task_file jobTaskRatingFile
jobDataFile OESfile

This should generate the data and plots as necessary."

When I run that in "Command Prompt", I get the following error, and I am not sure how to set the working directory correctly.
- python: can't open file 'cfProcessor_AEAPnP.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Thanks for the reading, and I hope there's someone who could help me!

Best regards & stay safe out there during Corona!!
Marc

Answer (score 1):

```
cf_dir, cf_file, cf_phys_file = sys.argv[1:4]
```

means, the python file expects few arguments when called.

In order to run

```
python cfProcessor_AEAPnP.py cf_dir cf_file cf_phys_file task_file jobTaskRatingFile jobDataFile OESfile
```

the command prompt should be in that folder.

So, open command prompt and type

```
cd path_to_the_folder_where_ur_python_file_is_located
```

Now, you would have reached the path of the python file.

Also, make sure you give full path in double quotes for the arguments.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response. Could you help what other arguments should I provide? Because the first (cf_dir) is a directory. How can I provide arguments for that?

Moreover, for running in the terminal, thanks! Now I get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cfProcessor_AEAPnP.py", line 8, in <module>
  import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'


How can I make sure it does import pandas?

Comment: `pandas` is python library for data analysis and manipulation. You must install it. That readme must have been more explicit on the python libraries you would need. Also, the arguments you need to provides are the path for the directory and both files

Comment: hi @DarK_FirefoX, thank you for the response. I am trying to figure out how to install pandas now, it does not seem intuitive. 

In the meanwhile, could you please(!) help me with how to code the argument for the path for the directory and both files? I'm stuck on this already for so long!

This is the path: C:\Users\Marc-Marijn Ossel\Documents\RSM\Thesis\Data\Suitable for ML\Data en Artikelen\Per task Suitability for Machine Learning score readme\cf_dir


Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Marc-MarijnOssel Pandas can be installed with `pip install pandas`.
The program expects the first argument to be cf_dir so, it should be
`python cfProcessor_AEAPnP.py "C:\Users\Marc-Marijn Ossel\Documents\RSM\Thesis\Data\Suitable for ML\Data en Artikelen\Per task Suitability for Machine Learning score readme\cf_dir" ...`

Note: The argument is given in double quotes, as there are spaces in the path.
Similarly, second argument, `cf_file` should be full path of `cf_file`.